# Can an a.s. non constant continuous martingale be differentiable with nonzero probability?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $M$ be a continuous martingale such that almost surely, the sample paths of $M$ are not constant.

**Question:** Is it true that $M$ is almost surely not differentiable?

Comment: $E[M_{t+h}-M_t|F_t] =0$ by the martingale property, but on the other hand, $E[h^{-1}(M_{t+h}-M_t)|F_t]\to^{h\to 0} M_t'$ by dominated convergence if you additionally assume that $M_t$ is $C$-Lipschitz almost surely. So $M_t'=0$ necessarily in this case.

Comment: @jlewk: While the argument is formally correct, I do not think it is useful here. A Lipschitz martingale is of bounded total variation, hence of zero quadratic variation. So the only martingales satisfying this conditions are constants anyway.

Comment: I stand corrected @StephanSturm. The question should link to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397639/does-there-exist-an-almost-surely-differentiable-martingale

Comment: Intuitively I would expect that by Martingale representation theorem all such processes can be realised as Ito integrals and are therefore indeed not differentiable a.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost surely, we can write for every $t \ge 0$, $M_t=M_0+\beta_{\langle M,M \rangle_t}$, where $\beta$ is some Brownian motion.

By Kahane's theorem, almost surely, for every $s \ge 0$, $\limsup_{\delta \to 0+} \delta^{-1/2}|\beta_{t+\delta}-\beta_t| \ge 1$.
https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1986-296-02/S0002-9947-1986-0846605-2/S0002-9947-1986-0846605-2.pdf

Let $b > a \ge 0$. Almost surely, on the event $M$ is differentiable on the time interval $[a,b[$, $\langle M,M \rangle_t$ and $M_t$ do not depend on $t$ on the time interval $[a,b]$.

Indeed, for every $t \in [a,b[$, since $M$ is differentiable at $t$ whereas
$$\limsup_{\delta \to 0+} \delta^{-1}|\beta_{\langle M,M \rangle_t+\delta}-\beta_{\langle M,M \rangle_t}| = +\infty,$$
we must have
$$\liminf_{h \to 0+} h^{-1}\big(\langle M,M \rangle_{t+h}-\langle M,M \rangle_t\big) = 0.$$
[Otherwise, the limsup as $h \to 0+$ of
$$\frac{M_{t+h}-M_t}{h} = \frac{M_{t+h}-M_t}{\langle M,M \rangle_{t+h}-\langle M,M \rangle_t} \times \frac{\langle M,M \rangle_{t+h}-\langle M,M \rangle_t}{h}$$
would be infinite, which would contradict the assumption.]

Given $\epsilon>0$, the set
$$S_\epsilon := \sup\{t \in [a,b] : \langle M,M \rangle_t - \langle M,M \rangle_a \le \epsilon(t-a)\}$$
contains $a$ and bounded above by $b$. Moreover, if $S_\epsilon$ contains $t \in [a,b[$, it contains $t+h$ for many arbitrarily small $h>0$. Hence $\sup S_\epsilon = b$ and $b \in S_\epsilon$ by left continuity.

As a result, $\langle M,M \rangle_b - \langle M,M \rangle_a \le \epsilon(b-a)$ for every $\epsilon>0$, so by monotonicity $\langle M,M \rangle_b = \langle M,M \rangle_a$ and $\langle M,M \rangle$ is constant on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you elaborate on how $d\langle M, M \rangle_t / dt = 0$ is derived? How is the result from Kahane’s theorem used?

Comment: @Nate River. I completed the proof.

Comment: Just read it, it’s a very nice proof. Thanks for your answer!